# Multiple attributes in jade

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I'm novice in Jade and I have an issue with adding attributes that depend on json data. Please see the code below:

`- var promoCode = data.promoCode
    - var instalments = data.instalments
div(class= promoCode === true ? "product__img-wrap_promo-code" : "")(class= instalments === true ? "product__img-wrap_instalments" : "")`

Now, it works fine for me, but I have a notification on the console like this:

C:\mobileGit\mobile_frontend\www\markup\modules\product_new\product_new.jade, line 11: You should not have jade tags with multiple attributes.

Maybe someone knows how to fix this trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with : http://jade-lang.com/demo/

```
- var promoCode = true
- var instalments = true

div(class=promoCode === true ? "product__img-wrap_promo-code" : "", class= instalments === true ? "product__img-wrap_instalments" : "")
```

**HTML Output :**

```
<div class="product__img-wrap_promo-code product__img-wrap_instalments"></div>
```